# Change value of select option based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Is there is way to change the value of select option if user check the check box. If user select "four" from select option, its default value is "4".Now if user check the checkbox, select option value becomes "44".

```
<select name="sel" id="MySelect">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
<option value="6">Six</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="btn_radio" />Discount
```

Comment: Put this in a jsFiddle and show us what you have tried thus far

Comment: What is your goal, more specifically? Do you want to change every option value (i.e. 3 becomes 33, 2 becomes 22) or only 4? And what happens when user unchecks the checkbox? Do options return to original values? And again: I suppose this select is inserted inside a form. Do you want to get modified value only on form submission?

Comment: Value change only for particular option selection like if user select  4, it becomes 44 on check and back to 4 when checkbox is unchecked and yes value modified on form submission

Comment: So the *only* time the checkbox should change the value is when the option `Four` is chosen? If someone selects the option `Two` (and checks the checkbox) the value should stay as `2`?

Comment: Yes, If selection of option is two and checkbox is checked than value should stay to 2 or checkbox will hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the `<option>` when the checkbox changes:

```js
(function() {

  var discount = document.getElementById("discount");
  var option = document.querySelector("#amount option[value='4']");

  discount.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      option.value = 44;
      option.textContent = "Fourty-Four";
    } else {
      option.value = 4;
      option.textContent = "Four";
    }
    console.log("value: %s, text: %s", option.value, option.textContent);
  });

})();
```

```html
<select id="amount">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
</select>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="discount" />Discount</label>
```

<sub>See also: `document.getElementById()`, `document.querySelector()`, and `EventTarget.addEventListener()`</sub>

Answer (score -2):

if I understand you correctly, and if you can use jQuery it should be possible.

Since you need to have **option** with value "44" you need to add/remove this option dynamically, when user check/uncheck checkbox.

I prepared simple example, it should be helpful for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/qv9nxhov/

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    //show current value
    $('.result').text($(this).val());

    //remove discount when choose other option
    $('select option[value="44"]').remove();
    $('input').attr('checked', false);
});

$('input').on('click', function() {
    //check if checkox is checked    
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //add extra option
        $('select').append('<option value="44" selected="selected">Discount</option>');
    } else {
        //remove extra option
        $('select option[value="44"]').remove();
    }
    //show current value
    $('.result').text($('select').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Your code is useful but it will be best if option with value 44 will not appear on check.